# How to use JSP <c:out> tag to set src of HTML <img> tag

Tags: html, jsp

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="view.jsp"><c:out value="${row.Title}"/> </a></td>
            <td><c:out value="${row.Description}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${row.AType}"/></td>
            <td><image  height="100px" width="200px" src="<c:out value="${row.LocURL}"/>"/></td>
       </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

---

I have tried the above code but it does not display the intended image, but a empty box.
Here LocURL is path to a image file which was retrieved from a database.
Please tell me how to make image appear inside the table according to the path provider by the  tag.

Answer (score 3):

Change `<image>` to `<img>`